# How to amend a form created from a CSV and using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, csv

I have a HTML/PHP form being displayed on a local page, its created using a jquery and datatables scripts. I was wondering if its possible to have editable sections of the displayed form, that could be changed by users on a submit button(submit button would need a password). I've posted the code i'm using below, there is the index.html that calls the scripts to run, and then the script.js that populates the tables.

**This is the index.html code**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>DRP Freelancer List 2017 </title>

    </head>

<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:71/css/demo_page.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:71/css/demo_table.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:71/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:71/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:71/css/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:71/css/styles.css" />

<noscript>
    <div id="noscript_note">You must have JavaScript enabled to view this page.</div>
</noscript>

<div id="H3"><h3>DRP Freelancer List 2017 <div id="pic"><img src="http://localhost:71/images/pbooklogo.png"></img></h3>

<div id="loading" title="Loading">
<p>Freelancing List is loading...</p>
</div>



<div id="table_info"></div>
<div id="table_div"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:71/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:71/scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:71/scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:71/scripts/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:71/scripts/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" `src="http://localhost:71/scripts/miso.ds.deps.ie.0.4.1.js"></script>`
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:71/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#loading").dialog();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**This is the script that calls the CSV file.**

```
// DataTables currency
// Use to sort the table via currency

// Where we'll put the data
var newDataSet = [];

// Our column headers
// Change these to fit your table
var tableColumnSet =   [
    { "sTitle": "Num", "sClass": "hidden" },
    { "sTitle": "Rating", "sClass": "center" },
    { "sTitle": "Confirmed On", "sClass": "center"},
    { "sTitle": "Employee" },
    { "sTitle": "Department" },
    { "sTitle": "Rate" },
    { "sTitle": "County"},
    { "sTitle": "Number", "sClass": "center" },
    { "sTitle": "Email", "sClass": "center" },
    { "sTitle": "Comments", "sClass": "center" },

];

// Our DataTable information
// Don't need to change anything here
// Unless you want to customize the table format
function showInfo() {
    $('#table_div').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table"></table>' );

    // Push the data to the table
    $('#table').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing":true,
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "iDisplayLength": 300,
        "aaData": newDataSet,
        "aoColumns": tableColumnSet,
        // Pick which column we will sort by default
        // For this table, we'll sort ascending by Total FY12 Salary
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
        }
    });

    $( "#loading" ).dialog( "destroy" );
    $( "#loading" ).html( "" );
}

// Load up the CSV using Miso.Dataset
$(document).ready( function() {
    // Change URL to the right path for your CSV
    var ds = new Miso.Dataset({
        url : '/Freelancers/csvs/salary_book_clean.csv',
        delimiter : ','
    });

    // Run this after we load our CSV
    ds.fetch({ success : function() {
        this.each(function(row, rowIndex) {
            // Change these variables to match your column names
        var NumData = row.Num;
            var RatingData = row.Rating;
            var ConfirmedOnData = row.ConfirmedOn;
            var employeeData = row.Employee;
            var departmentData = row.Department;
            var RateData = row.Rate;
            var countyData = row.County;
            var NumberData = row.Number;
            var EmailData = row.Email;
            var CommentsData = row.Comments;
            // Put information in an array and push it to our table
            // Change these variables to match variables above
            var myArray = [NumData, RatingData, ConfirmedOnData, employeeData, departmentData, RateData, countyData, NumberData, EmailData, CommentsData];
            newDataSet.push(myArray);
        });
        // Call DataTable function showInfo
        showInfo();
        $().ready(function() {
    var regEx = /(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)/;

    $("table td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).html().match(regEx);
    }).each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regEx, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>"));
    });

    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.aTypes.push(
    function ( sData )
    {
        var sValidChars = "0123456789,'£$.-";
        var Char;

        /* Check the numeric part */
        for ( i=1 ; i<sData.length ; i++ )
        {
            Char = sData.charAt(i);
            if (sValidChars.indexOf(Char) == -1)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /* Check prefixed by currency */
        if ( sData.charAt(5) == '$' || sData.charAt(5) == '£' )
        {
            return 'currency';
        }
        return null;
    }
);
});


    }});
});
```

Any help would be great.